# Vector Projection and Cross Product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let there be $w, u, $ and $v$, such that:
>   $$w \times u = \langle1, 3, 5\rangle$$
>   $$w \times v = \langle 2, 4, 6\rangle$$
>
> Find:
>   $$v \cdot (((u \times w) \times v) + \text{VP}uv(w)) + ((u \times v) \times w)$$

I honestly don't know where to start with this one. How would we find the vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited your question to use $\LaTeX$.  Please make sure it still represents your original intent.  (I wasn't sure what you meant by "VP", so I left it as-is...)  For help with formatting in the future, please see [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you! I tried looking at the formatting, but didn't understand it.. The VP is the vector projection.

Comment: To write math on this site all you need to know is you have to write it in between \$ and \$ or for display, \$\$ and \$\$. Inside the dollar signs you can write equations with variables normally but there are some special codes for things like fractions, symbols, many types of brackets, integrals etc. Take a look at anorton's edit to see what it looks like. Its not that hard to understand the code.

Comment: So does $\text{VP} uv(w)$ mean the projection of $w$ on to the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is that $v \cdot (((u \times w) \times v) + \text{VP}uv(w))$ is a dot product so it gives a number. But $((u + v) \times w)$ is a vector. So how can you add them?

Comment: I edited it.. it's supposed to be  $$ ((u \times v) \times w)$$

Comment: @user61653 The same problem remains. The dot product on the left gives a *number* but the triple cross product on the right gives a *vector* which still cannot be added together.

Comment: dot product gives you a vector as well

Comment: @user61653 NO. Dot production gives a number, not a vector. Look here:
http://planetmath.org/DotProduct.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: Yes, sorry I was thinking about cross product