# Determine the vectors $u, v, w$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let there be $w, u, $ and $v$, such that:
>   $$w \times u = \langle1, 3, 5\rangle$$
>   $$w \times v = \langle 2, 4, 6\rangle$$
>
> Find:
>   $$v \cdot (((u \times w) \times v) + \text{VP}uv(w)) + ((u + v) \times w)$$

How would the vectors $u, v, w$ be determined?

$w \times u = \langle1, 3, 5\rangle$ and
$w \times v = \langle 2, 4, 6\rangle$
would mean that $w$ is perpendicular to those vectors right?

Comment: This question is very similar to your previous two questions (found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324339/vector-projection-and-cross-product) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326052/determine-a-vector-given-vector-the-scalar-and-vector-projection)).  What have you tried?

Comment: I multiplied the two vectors above together and that would be the vector for $w$ so $w = \langle-1,2,-1\rangle$ and then I don't know what else to do

Comment: I am really stuck on this question, but didn't get responses.

Comment: What does $VPuv(w)$ mean? The other operations are common, dot product and cross product. Also maybe one doesn't need to know each of $u,v,w$ individually in order to determine the expression after "Find:" in the stated question.

Comment: $VPuv(w)$ is vector projection

Comment: Have you made any progress, using my hints, or otherwise?

Comment: I used the rules so I got something like $-(v.w)u + (v.u)w + (((uxv).w)/w^2)$ but $(((uxv).w)/w^2$ is perpendicular so it would be zero? Is this on the right track?

Comment: I don't know what $w^2$ means, I don't know what it means for one thing to be perpendicular (perpendicularity is a relation involving two things), and I don't know why something being perpendicular would make it zero, so I am at a loss to understand what you have done. You might make some progress if you try to make use of my hints.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1. The dot product distributes over addition.
2. The dot product of perpendicular vectors is zero.
3. $B$ is perpendicular to $A\times B$.
4. The cross product distributes over addition.
5. The cross product is anti-symmetric.

Comment: So I can use your hints to simplify the equation without having to find what $u, v, w$ are?

Comment: Not if you just sit there asking questions, you can't. But maybe if you actually try to implement them, you'll find I posted them for a reason. Further notes: 1. you write, "simplify the equation", but you have no equation. 2. I don't know what "vector projection" is.